# SQL Check Contraint for list of rules

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm hoping someone will be able to help me with this. I'd like to create Check constraints for different categories of drivers license and the minimum age to qualify. For example

```
Category  -  Age

AM   -       16

A2    -      18

A      -     24
```

I think I have to do a number of separate constraints to do this. I think I have all the pieces, I just need some help with bringing it all together.

Here is the SQL to check a valid license category has been entered;

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY public."salespeople"

ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Driverslicense CHECK (spDriverslicense IN ('AM', 'A1', 'A2', 'A', 'B', 'BE', 'W', 'C', 'CE', 'C1', 'C1E', 'D', 'DE', 'D1', 'D1E'));
```

The DB only has a date of birth column, doesn't have a 'years old' column. I can get the age;

```
SELECT *,  age(current_date, spdob)

FROM public."salespeople";
```

I'm having problems bringing them together.

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY public."salespeople"

ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_AM_16YO CHECK (spDriverslicense = 'AM' AND (age(current_date, spdob) > 16));
```

The error I get is

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: interval > integer 
HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I think the problem is that age = 30 years 3 months 10 days etc so it can't be compared to an integer. This is where I'm stuck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `age()` function returns an `INTERVAL` and therefore cannot be used in a comparison with an integer (e.g. `[interval] > 16`).

However you can extract the *year* component of the interval using the `extract()` function, and that can be compared to an integer:

`EXTRACT(year FROM AGE(current_date, spdob)) > 16`

For example, `SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM interval '12 years 11 months')` returns `12`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `age()`.  Instead, just use date comparisons:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY public."salespeople"
    ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_AM_16YO
        CHECK (spDriverslicense = 'AM' AND
               spdob >= current_date - interval '16 year'
              );
```

Comment: Thanks Eurotrash and Gordon, both those solutions work. The next issue is how do you deal with competing check constraints. The error I'm getting now is ERROR: check constraint "chk_am_16yo" is violated by some row. So I need to figure out how to set it up that it only looks for the records that has 'AM' and check the age of those records. Thanks.

Comment: @Dakan_GIS `ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_AM_16YO CHECK (spDriverslicense <> 'AM' OR [the age bit here])` - so if spDriverslicense is not AM, then the first part is TRUE and the check passes; if it is FALSE (i.e. the value is 'AM') then the second part will have to be TRUE to pass the check.

Comment: Genius! Thank Eurotrash. That did the job.